# Trying to modify custom search function in plugin to search postmeta table for keyword as well as posts table

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I am trying to modify a plugin that searches the posts table and have it also search the meta_value in the postmeta table.

original code is:

```
if (!($index_page = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID AS id, post_name AS slug FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE (post_content LIKE '%[" . W2DC_MAIN_SHORTCODE . "]%' OR post_content LIKE '%[" . W2DC_MAIN_SHORTCODE . " %') AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'page' LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A)))
```

and my code so far is:

```
if (!($index_page = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.ID AS id, {$wpdb->posts}.post_name AS slug FROM {$wpdb->posts} INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id) WHERE 1 = 1 AND (({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value LIKE '%[" . W2DC_MAIN_SHORTCODE . "]%') OR  ({$wpdb->posts}.post_content LIKE '%[" . W2DC_MAIN_SHORTCODE . "]%')) AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'page' AND (({$wpdb->postmeta}.metakey = '_content_field_6') OR ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_content_field_11'))LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A)))
```

but its not working and i cannot figure out why... any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an instance of `metakey` which should be `meta_key`.

Comment: thanks, that wasn't the issue overall though :(